# `skak` and `xskak`. Command `\continuevariationcurrent` causes compilation error under `xskak`

Tags: chess, xskak, skak

I understand package `xskak` to be an extension of `skak`, but that there are some incompatibilities due to overlaps in funcionality. I would like to work with `xskak` in the long term, but hoped to be able to include pure `skak` code while getting there. Compiling `skak` code under `xskak` seemed to go well until I came across Torben Hoffmann's `Example of the LaTeX-input and output of an annotated chess game using skak.sty` dated January 8, 2018. The command `\continuevariationcurrent` causes a `! Paragraph ended before \FenBoard was complete` error.

```
\documentclass{article}
%=======================
%\usepackage{skak}
\usepackage{xskak}
%=======================
\begin{document}
\fenboard{1q3kr1/3rb2p/p3Q3/8/1p6/8/PPP3PP/4R2K w - - 0 26}
\showboard

Fischer - Tal after \movecomment{25... Kf8!}

\mainline{26. Qxd7}

Not \variation{26. Rf1+ Kg7 27. Rf7+ Kh8} and if 
%\continuevariationcurrent{28. Qxd7 Rd8 29. Qg4 Qe5} wins.

\mainline{26...Qd6 27. Qb7 Rg6} 

Within a handful of moves the game has changed its complexion.
Now it is White who must fight for a draw!

\mainline{28. c3} 
Black's extra piece means less with each pawn that's exchanged.

\mainline{28...a5} 

On \variation{28...bxc3 29. Qc8+ Bd8 30. Qxc3}=.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use "pure skak" with `xskak`. `xskak` has a different view about `\mainline` and `variation` then `skak`. With `skak` `\variation` changes the level, also `skak` tries to play (that means to update the internal board) with both commands. With `xskak` only `\mainline` plays, while `\variation` only prints, and change of levels are done with `invar` and `outvar`.

This difference means that there is actually no need for a special `\continuevariation`, it can simply be mapped to `\variation`. This will avoid the error, but you won't get the same output as with `skak`: both commands will use the main bold style unless you add `invar` and `outvar` (the last still bold variation shows this).

```
\documentclass{article}
%=======================
\usepackage{xskak}
\let\continuevariation\variation %if wanted ...

%=======================
\begin{document}
\fenboard{1q3kr1/3rb2p/p3Q3/8/1p6/8/PPP3PP/4R2K w - - 0 26}
\showboard

Fischer - Tal after \movecomment{25... Kf8!}

\mainline{26. Qxd7}

Not \variation[invar]{26. Rf1+ Kg7 27. Rf7+ Kh8} and if
\continuevariation{28. Qxd7 Rd8 29. Qg4 Qe5} wins.

\mainline[outvar]{26...Qd6 27. Qb7 Rg6}

Within a handful of moves the game has changed its complexion.
Now it is White who must fight for a draw!

\mainline{28. c3}
Black's extra piece means less with each pawn that's exchanged.

\mainline{28...a5}

On \variation{28...bxc3 29. Qc8+ Bd8 30. Qxc3}=.

\end{document}
```

[image]